# Unable to return value to caller function scala

Tags: scala, druid

I am trying to call one of the utility functions, but unable to return value to the caller, but somehow I am not able to return the response to the caller; i.e the main function. What could be the issue?

I tried reassigning the response to a local variable and returning that; but did not work

```
// main function
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val res = fetchFromDruid()
  // res comes as null here
}

def fetchFromDruid(): GroupByResponse {
  // creating an execution context

  // creating a local druid client

  // constructing a group by query

  // executing the query
  client(query).onComplete {
    //this will be executed if data is fetched successfully
    case Success(response) =>
      return response

    //this will be executed if there is an exception
    case Failure(ex) =>
      ex.printStackTrace()
      return null
  }
}
```

Expected: The main method (caller) should get the response

Actual: The caller does not get the response after the callback returns

Comment: This is invalid syntax. I get "error: illegal start of declaration (possible cause: missing `=' in front of current method body)". Even if the syntax were right, it wouldn't compile, as the return type of `onComplete` is `Unit`, not `GroupByResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:

```
def f() :Unit = return 3

val x = f()  //x: Unit = ()
```

You can't return a value from a method that doesn't return a value, which is what your code is trying to do.

Look at the type signature of `onComplete()`.

```
abstract def onComplete(f: (Try[T]) ⇒ U)(executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

`onComplete()` appends new code to the end of a `Future` executing on a separate thread. The code will, eventually, be executed but `onComplete()` returns `Unit` (no useful value) to the caller right away, so your `return` statements are meaningless. (And poor Scala style. Don't use `return`. It will mislead you.)

Comment: Also, the `fetchFromDruid` definition is missing a `=` so it will always return `Unit`.